# Error in including a library in makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran

I have some troubles with including a library in a makefile.

The library `nlopt` is installed in `/usr/lib` and my program properly runs when I compile it from command line:

`gfortran -I/usr/include main.f90 -L/usr/lib -lnlopt -lm -o exec`

However I need to use a makefile. The one below seems to be fine but it doesn't work, I get:

`main.f90:19: Error: Can't open included file 'nlopt.f'`

Could you help in finding the bug, please?

---

```
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include  

LFLAGS = -L/usr/lib  

LIBS = -lnlopt -lm

objects =  main.o

f90comp = gfortran

exec: $(objects)  
    $(f90comp) $(INCLUDES) -o exec $(objects) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.f90
    $(f90comp) -c main.f90

clean:
    rm *.o *.mod exec
    rm $(objects)

# End of the makefile
```

(Before $(f90comp) and rm, there are Tab)

Comment: Where is the file `nlopt.f`? Is it in `usr/include`? And are you sure the compiler doesn't care about argument order? (I'd try the *exact* same order to be sure.)

Comment: Can you show the entire output from `make`? I have a feeling the line immediately before your error message would be instructive.

Comment: It is also sometimes useful to try `make -n` as that will show you only what commands make is trying to run.

Answer (score 4):

Your error message tells you that `nlopt.f`, which you are including in your `main.f90`, is not available at compile time. A path to this file needs to be provided to the compiler. You are doing this correctly in your one liner, because you compile and link in one go while providing the path:

```
gfortran -I/usr/include main.f90 -L/usr/lib -lnlopt -lm -o exec
```

Because this works and `make` does not, `nlopt.f` apparently does not sit in the same directory as `main.f90`, but rather in `/usr/include`. You need to modify the compile line in your Makefile:

```
main.o: main.f90
    $(f90comp) -I/usr/include -c main.f90
```