# Sorting in Fortran, undefined reference to qsort_

Tags: linux, fortran

I'm a beginner of fortran and Linux.I ran a simple fortran program named `demo.f90` on Linux. Then an error occurred, as follow.

```
/tmp/cckAhxOW.o: In function `MAIN__':
demo.f90:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `qsort_'
```

The code is attached below.

```
program trand

external compar

integer*2 compar

INTEGER*4 array(10)/5,1,9,0,8,7,3,4,6,2/,l/10/,isize/4/

call qsort( array, l, isize, compar )

write(*,'(10i3)') array

end program trand

integer*2 function compar( a, b )

INTEGER*4 a, b

if ( a .lt. b ) compar = -1

if ( a .eq. b ) compar = 0

if ( a .gt. b ) compar = 1

return

end function compar
```

Comment: You didn't link the program with the library containing qsort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do better to put `compare` into a module and `use` it.   This approach will allow the compiler to check for consistency between your call of the subroutine and its declaration.  If the main program and the module are in the same file, put the module first.

```
module MySubs

contains

integer*2 function compar( a, b )
...
end function compar

end module MySubs

program trand

use MySubs
use SomeMod

....

end program trand
```

Where `SomeMod` is a module in another file SomeMod.f90 with the sorting routine qsort.  Then compile and link:

```
gfortran SomeMod.f90 trand.f90
```

or whatever compiler and filenames you are using.  The file with `qsort` needs to be before the file with `program trand`.

Comment: I do not believe alone this will help. See my answer.

Comment: I was assuming that the person asking the question had Fortran source code for a qsort. If not, this is not a beginner problem.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort` is actualy a C standard library function. You have to declare an interface to it. It goes like this:

```
module Sort
  use iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  interface
    subroutine qsort(array,elem_count,elem_size,compare) bind(C,name="qsort")
      import
      type(c_ptr),value       :: array
      integer(c_size_t),value :: elem_count
      integer(c_size_t),value :: elem_size
      type(c_funptr),value    :: compare !int(*compare)(const void *, const void *)
    end subroutine qsort !standard C library qsort
  end interface
end module Sort


program trand

use Sort

external compar

integer(c_int) compar

integer(c_int),target :: array(10) = [5,1,9,0,8,7,3,4,6,2]
integer(c_size_t) l/10/,isize/4/

call qsort( c_loc(array(1)), l, isize, c_funloc(compar) )

write(*,'(10i3)') array

end program trand

integer(c_int) function compar( a, b ) bind(C)
use iso_c_binding

integer(c_int) a, b

if ( a .lt. b ) compar = -1

if ( a .eq. b ) compar = 0

if ( a .gt. b ) compar = 1

end function compar
```

Then just compile as you did. Tested succesfully with gfortran 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` is not a built-in subroutine (a.k.a. *intrinsic* subroutine).

You need to tell the program where to find it, for instance by loading a module which contains this subroutine (see the `use` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Try including "libfui.a"  library

Comment: @user3163883 how are you building?

Comment: @user3163883 you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865015/fortran-error-in-including-a-library-in-makefile

Comment: gfortran demo.f90 -o demo

Comment: This is too complicated for a beginner like me.

Comment: The "libfui.a" library is part of the runtime libraries of the Oracle Fortran compiler. I wouldn't really recommend using that with gfortran. You might aswell just use the Oracle compiler.